# Cloned Elements Don't Work After Being Cloned To The DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-select2

I'm using the [jquery snap-to-increment slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) and also [select2.js for dropdowns](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). When I click on the `.append-new-skills` class it should clone the div's, slider and select dropdown.

It does clone all of these element but they are unfortunately not clickable or functional in anyway, just visually present.

I understand that HTML `id` tags have to be unique but unsure of the best way to incorporate all of these elements.

My Question: How do I make each of the newly added elements functional when loaded into the DOM after the initial page load?

Initialise of Select Dropdown Within `<head></head>` tags:

```
    $(".select-some-skills").select2({
        placeholder: "+ Add Type",
        allowClear: true
    });
```

Initial DOM Load (HTML):

```
        <div class="single-skill overflow-hidden">
            <div class="float-left select-skill-margin">
                <select class="jobseeker-skill-select select-some-skills"></select> 
            </div>  
            <div class="float-left slider-skill-margin">
                <span style="margin-left:-37px;" id="skill-level" class="center color-blue skill-level"></span>
                <div id="slider" class="slide">
                    <div class="inner-slider-marker"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var sliderAmountMap = ["Beginner", "Average", "Intermediate", "Excellent", "Expert"];

    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0, //array index of onload selected default value on slider, for example, 45000 in same array will be selected as default on load
        min: 0, //the values will be from 0 to array length-1
        max: sliderAmountMap.length-1, //the max length, slider will snap until this point in equal width increments
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#skill-level").text( sliderAmountMap[ui.value] ); //map selected "value" with lookup array

            var popover_movement = ( $("#slider").width() )/4;
            var half_span_width = ( $('#skill-level').width() )/2;

            if(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Beginner"){
                popover_movement = 0;
            }else if(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Average"){
                popover_movement = popover_movement*1;
            }else if(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Intermediate"){
                popover_movement = popover_movement*2;
            }else if(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Excellent"){
                popover_movement = popover_movement*3;
            }else if(sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Expert"){
                popover_movement = popover_movement*4;
            }

            popover_movement = popover_movement - half_span_width;

            console.log( popover_movement );
            $( "#skill-level" ).css("margin-left", popover_movement + "px");
        }
    });
    $( "#skill-level" ).text( sliderAmountMap[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value")] );//map selected "value" with lookup array
}); 

$(document).on('click', '.append-new-skill', function() {
    $('.single-skill:first').clone().appendTo('.dashboard-main-content');
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: try `var clonedObj = $('.single-skill:first').clone(true); $('.dashboard-main-content').append(clonedObj);`

Comment: This now means that the **first slider or select box** in the DOM reacts whenever I interact with any of the cloned sliders or select boxes, so not really what, I've edited my question to give more detail

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: I unfortunately don't know how.

Comment: Just go to http://jsfiddle.net and copy your HTML into the HTML box, your jQuery into the JavaScript Box, and then go to the left sidebar and include the libraries you mention. Save it, then give us the link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V9nfE/ I hope this helps, make give you a bit more understanding of what's going on

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22919034/569751) solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/V9nfE/7/

$(function () {

```
    var sliderAmountMap = ["Beginner", "Average", "Intermediate", "Excellent", "Expert"];
    var sliderOptions = {
        value: 0, //array index of onload selected default value on slider, for example, 45000 in same array will be selected as default on load
        min: 0, //the values will be from 0 to array length-1
        max: sliderAmountMap.length - 1, //the max length, slider will snap until this point in equal width increments
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var $parent = $(ui.handle).closest('.dashboard-main-content');
            //console.log($parent);
            $parent.find(".skill-level").text(sliderAmountMap[ui.value]); //map selected "value" with lookup array

            var popover_movement = ($parent.find(".slider").width()) / 4;
            var half_span_width = ($parent.find('.skill-level').width()) / 2;

            if (sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Beginner") {
                popover_movement = 0;
            } else if (sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Average") {
                popover_movement = popover_movement * 1;
            } else if (sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Intermediate") {
                popover_movement = popover_movement * 2;
            } else if (sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Excellent") {
                popover_movement = popover_movement * 3;
            } else if (sliderAmountMap[ui.value] == "Expert") {
                popover_movement = popover_movement * 4;
            }
            popover_movement = popover_movement - half_span_width;
            console.log($parent);
            $parent.find(".skill-level").css("margin-left", popover_movement + "px");
        }
    }

    var copyOfParent = $('.dashboard-main-content').clone();

    function applySelect2() {
        $(".jobseeker-skill-select:last").select2({
            placeholder: "+ Add Type",
            allowClear: true
        });
    }

    applySelect2();


    $(".slider").slider(sliderOptions);
    $(".skill-level").text(sliderAmountMap[$(".slider").slider("value")]); //map selected "value" with lookup array

    $(document).on('click', '.append-new-skill', function () {
        $('#dashboard-main').append(copyOfParent.clone());
        $('.slider:last').slider(sliderOptions);
        applySelect2();
        $(".skill-level:last").text(sliderAmountMap[$(".slider:last").slider("value")]); //map selected "value" with lookup array
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The slider now works when cloned but unfortunately I'm trying to get the `<select>` area to work after they are cloned. I'm using select2.js for my select areas. So this only answers part of my question.

Comment: What you want with select?

Comment: I'm currently using this jquery plugin http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ in order to style my `<select></select>` the way I want with CSS. Unfortunately the `<select></select>` don't work after being cloned. I want to be able to clone the `<select></select>` as well as the sliders.

Comment: Try now. Select also works. I have the updated my answer and the link.

Comment: What a star! You've solved this nagging problem for me. Really appreciate you taking the time to help. I've just +1 and accepted your answer. Again Thanks Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to bind the event to each of these clones with the cloning process.

I mean like:

```
 $('.single-skill:first').clone().appendTo('.dashboard-main-content').click(function(e){
alert("hi");
});
```

like that, you can add the functionality or the initialization to the element you want to carryout.